# DB2 SQL Error in creating a new function with params and returning a table

Tags: sql, db2

I wrote a simple query and it works. I want to make it a function. But it gives me an error -

```
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "DISTINCT" was found following "BEGIN
 RETURN SELECT".  Expected tokens may include:  "(".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

The function is -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CSE532.NEIGHBOR_LIST (IN_ZIP VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS TABLE (NEIGHBOR VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT DISTINCT substr(b.GEOID10,1,5) FROM CSE532.USZIP a, CSE532.USZIP b WHERE db2gse.st_intersects(a.SHAPE,b.SHAPE) = 1 AND substr(a.GEOID10,1,5) = IN_ZIP;
END
```

All the columns exist

Comment: Does it work if you remove the DISTINCT?

Comment: What tool do you use to run this statement? Change the statement separator in your tool to, let’s say, `@`, place it at the end of the statement and try again.

Comment: @mark-barinstein DBeaver is the gui I use. Let me try with your suggestion.

Comment: @CaiusJard doesnt work

Comment: When you remove the distinct what error do you see then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the BEGIN and END

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CSE532.NEIGHBOR_LIST (IN_ZIP VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS TABLE (NEIGHBOR VARCHAR(5))
    RETURN SELECT DISTINCT substr(b.GEOID10,1,5) FROM CSE532.USZIP a, CSE532.USZIP b WHERE db2gse.st_intersects(a.SHAPE,b.SHAPE) = 1 AND substr(a.GEOID10,1,5) = IN_ZIP
```

or use BEGIN ATOMIC

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CSE532.NEIGHBOR_LIST (IN_ZIP VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS TABLE (NEIGHBOR VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN ATOMIC
    RETURN SELECT DISTINCT substr(b.GEOID10,1,5) FROM CSE532.USZIP a, CSE532.USZIP b WHERE db2gse.st_intersects(a.SHAPE,b.SHAPE) = 1 AND substr(a.GEOID10,1,5) = IN_ZIP;
END
```